# soap_in() missing compilation error for gSOAP

Tags: c++, wsdl, gsoap

I'm working on a existing C++ project which uses gSOAP. I have switched from std::string to custom one and trying to force gSOAP to use it instead.
I have defined following file for soapcpp2:

```
//env.h
extern class Wlp::string;
extern typedef Wlp::string wlpstring;
```

Bodies of following functions were defined: **soap_serialize_wlpstring()**, **soap_default_wlpstring()**, **soap_out_wlpstring()**, **soap_in_wlpstring()**.

In subprojects I use following declaration in  **'*.dat'** files:

```
xsd__string = #import "wlp_string_gsoap.h" | wlpstring
```

I get compilation error because in one of the subprojects gSOAP generates a code from ***.wsdl** with **wlpstring::soap_in()** and **wlpstring::soap_out()** member function calls.

Why does gSOAP generate code that uses **soap_in()** member function for the string instead of calling **soap_in_wlpstring()** global function?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but I've been able to trigger similar behaviour by dropping the `extern` modifier from `wlp::string` in `wlp_string_gsoap.h`. This appears to cause `soapcpp2` to expect the class to have a full set of declared `soap_*` methods (including, but definitely not limited to, `soap_in` and `soap_out`) that it will then provide implementations for in the generated serialisation code. Perhaps this modifier has been dropped in one of your subprojects?